# Excel File Upload with Kendo UI

Tags: excel, kendo-asp.net-mvc

while I was trying to upload an excel file with kendo ui I found a code on the internet. It is using a keyword named "Constants" but this keyword does not recognize the ".xls" file extension. I am stuck at this and did some research but have no answer to solve this. Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Submit(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
           if(files!= null)
           {
               string fileName;
               string filePath;
               string fileExtension;
               foreach(var f in files)
               {
                   //Set file details
                   SetFileDetails(f, out fileName, out filePath, out fileExtension);

                   if(fileExtension == Constants.xls || fileExtension == Constants.xlsx)
                   {
                       //Save the uploaded file to app folder
                       string savedExcelFiles = Constants.UploadedFolder + fileName;
                       f.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savedExcelFiles));

                       ReadDataFromExcelFiles(savedExcelFiles);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //file not supported send alert
                   }

               }
           }
           return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index","Connect");
        }

        private static void SetFileDetails(HttpPostedFileBase f,out string fileName,out string filePath,out string fileExtension)
        {
            fileName=Path.GetFileName(f.FileName);
            fileExtension=Path.GetExtension(f.FileName);
            filePath = Path.GetFullPath(f.FileName);
        }

        private void ReadDataFromExcelFiles(string savedExcelFiles)
        {
            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;",Server.MapPath(savedExcelFiles));

            //fill the DataSet by the sheets
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            List<UploadExcel> uploadExl = new List<UploadExcel>();

            adapter.Fill(ds,"Subscriber");
            DataTable data=ds.Tables["Subscriber"];

            GetSetUploadExcelData(uploadExl,data);
        }

        private static void GetSetUploadExcelData (List<UploadExcel> uploadExl,DataTable data)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<data.Rows.Count-1;i++)
            {
                UploadExcel NewUpload = new UploadExcel();
                NewUpload.ID = Convert.ToInt16(data.Rows[i]["ID"]);
                NewUpload.CostCenter = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["CostCenter"]);
                NewUpload.FirstName = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["FirstName"]);
                NewUpload.LastName = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["LastName"]);

                NewUpload.MobileNo = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["MobileNo"]);
                NewUpload.EmailID = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["EmailID"]);
                NewUpload.Services = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["Services"]);

                NewUpload.UsageType = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["UsageType"]);
                NewUpload.Network = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["Network"]);
                NewUpload.UsageIncluded = Convert.ToInt16(data.Rows[i]["UsageIncluded"]);
                NewUpload.Unit = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["Unit"]);

                uploadExl.Add(NewUpload);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `Constants.xls` relates to a static `class` or `enum` that the original code author is using to hold the .xls/.xlsx extensions.

If you create a constants class something like:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string xls = "xls";
    public static string xlsx = "xlsx";
}
```

This would then should help.

If you need any more assistance then please let me know.

**edit**: Just reviewing the code it seems they are also putting in constant mapping for the uploadfolder location as well so I suspect this is just a static class rather than an enum with application specific details. in a way a bit like using the `appSettings` within webconfig

Comment: Code snippets does not work as you said it is not a static field,but I will try it all over again may be I missed something,thanks for your attention,have a nice day.